# PDF not getting generated when using iText API with CSS

Tags: java, html, css, pdf, itext

I am trying to generate pdf from HTML having CSS.

Below is the code snippet

```
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(outFileName));

        document.open();

        String htmlTxt = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(dirPath + inpFileName), "UTF-8");
        ByteArrayInputStream fis = new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlTxt.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        XMLWorkerHelper worker = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();
        // worker.parseXHtml(pdfWriter, document, fis);

        worker.parseXHtml(pdfWriter, document, new FileInputStream(dirPath + inpFileName),
                new FileInputStream(CSS));

        // close the document
        document.close();
        // close the writer
        pdfWriter.close();
```

I tried generating pdf using 
**worker.parseXHtml(pdfWriter, document, fis);**
PDF gets generated without

which worked fine then used 
**worker.parseXHtml(pdfWriter, document, new FileInputStream(dirPath + inpFileName), new FileInputStream(CSS));**
In this case pdf gets generated but without any content .

I also tried how to use CSS resolver as suggested in [iText Parse HTML with CSS Example](http://www.itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker/D04_ParseHtmlCss)

IMPORTANT Note -- The HTML has been generated from jTidy API.
Here is the HTML and CSS file

```css
#pdfPreview { font-family: arial }

#pdfPreview .page_1 {position:relative; overflow: hidden;padding: 0px;border: none;width: 90%;margin:0 auto;}
#pdfPreview .page_1 .id_1 {border:none;margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;padding: 0px;border:none;width: 100%;overflow: hidden;}
#pdfPreview .page_1 .id_2 {border:none;margin: 107px 0px 0px 8px;padding: 0px;border:none;width: 720px;overflow: hidden;}

#pdfPreview .page_1 #dimg1 {position:absolute;top:181px;left:0px;z-index:-1;width:736px;height:677px;}
#pdfPreview .page_1 #dimg1 #img1 {width:736px;height:677px;}

#pdfPreview .page_1 #inl_img1 {position:relative;width:7px;height:17px;}



#pdfPreview #page_2 {position:relative; overflow: hidden;margin: 41px 0px 37px 40px;padding: 0px;border: none;width: 776px;}
#pdfPreview #page_2 #pdfPreview .id_1 {border:none;margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;padding: 0px;border:none;width: 776px;overflow: hidden;}
#pdfPreview #page_2 .id_2 {border:none;margin: 28px 0px 0px 8px;padding: 0px;border:none;width: 720px;overflow: hidden;}

#pdfPreview #page_2 #dimg1 {position:absolute;top:7px;left:0px;z-index:-1;width:741px;height:935px;}
#pdfPreview #page_2 #dimg1 #img1 {width:741px;height:935px;}

#pdfPreview .vehicleDescriptionTable{
    border: black 1px solid;
}

#pdfPreview .vehicleDescriptionTable table tr td:nth-child(1){
 width: 3%;
    padding-left: 1%;
}

#pdfPreview .vehicleDescriptionTable table tr td:nth-child(2){
     width: 57%;
}

#pdfPreview .vehicleDescriptionTable table tr td:nth-child(3){
     width: 3%;
    padding-left: 1%;
}

#pdfPreview .vehicleDescriptionTable table tr td:nth-child(4){
     width: 37%;
}

#pdfPreview td{
 vertical-align: top;
}

#pdfPreview tr{
 /* line-height: 0em; */
}

#pdfPreview html {
    font:  13px 'Arial';
}

#pdfPreview p.sectionHead {
    text-align: center;
    font: 16px 'Arial' bold;
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 2em;
    padding-top: .5em;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-top: black 1px solid;
    border-left: black 1px solid;
    border-right: black 1px solid;
    /* width: 774px; */
}

#pdfPreview p.subSectionHead {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #eee;
    margin-top: 0;
    height: 1.5em;
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-top: .2em;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    /* border-bottom: none; */
    /* border-right: black 1px solid; */
    /* width: 100%; */
}

#pdfPreview table {
    /* border: 1px solid black; */
    border-bottom: 4em;
    width: 100%;
}

#pdfPreview td:nth-child(3) {
    border-left: black 1px solid;
}

#pdfPreview tbody {
    border-bottom: black 1px solid;
    /* padding-bottom: 1em; */
}

#pdfPreview p {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: .2em;
}

#pdfPreview .floatright{
 float: right;
 text-align: right;
}

#pdfPreview .floatleft{
 float:left;
 text-align: left;
}

#pdfPreview .topmargin{
 margin-top:.4em;
}

/*Melissa Page2*/
#pdfPreview #page2, #vehicleListTable, #table3 {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}
#pdfPreview #page2 thead {
  background-color: #eee;
}
#pdfPreview #page2 thead th:first-child {
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
  text-align: left;
}
#page2 thead th:nth-child(2) {
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
  text-align: right;
}
#pdfPreview #page2 tbody .simple td {
  font-weight: bold;
}
#pdfPreview #page2 tbody .simple td p {
  font-weight: normal;
}
#pdfPreview #page2 tbody .header {
  width: 15%;
  padding: .3rem;
  background-color: #eee;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#pdfPreview #page2 tbody .subheader {
  width: 10%;
  padding: .3rem;
}
#pdfPreview #page2 tbody .subtableheader {
  text-align: center;
}
#pdfPreview #page2 tbody .fillout {
  padding: .3rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: #E6E6E6;
}
#pdfPreview #page2 tbody .filledout {
  padding: .3rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}
#page2 tbody .bottomrow {
  padding-bottom: 6rem;
  text-align: left;
}

#pdfPreview .border-top {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#pdfPreview .border-top-left{
 border-left: 1px solid black;
 border-top: 1px solid black;
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
#pdfPreview .border-middle-left {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
#pdfPreview .border-middle-fix{
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
#pdfPreview .border-middle {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
#pdfPreview .bottom-left {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
#pdfPreview .bottom-right {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

#pdfPreview .footer1{
 margin-bottom:4em;
}

#pdfPreview td.topmargin{
 width:50%;
}

#pdfPreview .footerClass{
 width:90%;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding-bottom:4em;
}

#pdfPreview .mainBodyHeadArea{
 border-left:1px solid black;
 border-right:1px solid black;
 border-top:1px solid black;
}

#pdfPreview .submissionCellLeft{
 width:50%;
 padding:1em;
}

#pdfPreview .submissionCellRight{
 width: 50%;
 padding:1em;
 border-left: 1px solid black;
}

#pdfPreview td.addressCity {
    width: 40%;
}

#pdfPreview td.addressZip {
    width: 20%;
}

#pdfPreview td.addressState {
    width: 20%;
}

#pdfPreview td.addressCountry {
    width: 20%;
    border-left:none;
}

#pdfPreview table{
 border-spacing: 0;
}

#pdfPreview .addressRow{
 padding: 0;
}

#pdfPreview #vehicleListTable th, #pdfPreview #vehicleListTable td {
 padding:.5em;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#pdfPreview .filloutHeight{
 height:1em;
}

#pdfPreview .borderLeft{
 border-left:1px solid black;
}

#pdfPreview .fillAddressCity,.fillAddressState,.fillAddressCountry,.fillAddressZip{
 margin-left: 3em;
}

#pdfPreview .center{
 text-align: center;
}

#pdfPreview #vehicleListTable, #pdfPreview #table3 {
 width:90%;
 margin:0 auto;
}

#pdfPreview  td {
 padding:.5em;
}




#pdfPreview {
    width: 800px;
}

#pdfPreview p, td{
  font-size:12px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet href="foo.css" media="all" type="text/css"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="generator"
content="HTML Tidy for Java (vers. 2009-12-01), see jtidy.sourceforge.net" />
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>PDF HTML Title</title>
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="previewStylesPDF.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="pdfPreview">
<table id="page2">
<thead>
<tr>
<th colspan="2" class="border-top-left">Table Title</th>
<th colspan="6" class="border-top">Author Name</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="simple">
<td colspan="8" class="border-middle-left">Single or Multiple
Vehicle Registration for a Single Customer</td>
</tr>
<tr class="simple">
<td colspan="8" class="border-middle-left">
<p>Instructions for members only: Scan and upload this
completed and <b><ins style="font-weight: bold">signed</ins> form
to the mail-id <a
href="#">myName@Company.com</a></b></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="header border-middle-left">Dealer</td>
<td class="subheader border-middle-fix">Dealer Name</td>
<td colspan="4" class="border-middle fillDealerName filledout">
Mercedez</td>
<td class="subheader border-middle">Phone</td>
<td colspan="2" class="border-middle fillDealerPhone filledout">
(###)###-####</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="subheader border-middle-left">Name Dealer Code</td>
<td class="border-middle-fix fillDealerCode filledout">BorderLand</td>
<td class="subheader border-middle">Dealer Contact Name</td>
<td colspan="3" class="border-middle fillDealerContact filledout">
</td>
<td class="subheader border-middle">Email</td>
<td class="border-middle fillDealerEmail filledout"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table id="vehicleListTable">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="header border-middle-left">Serial Number</th>
<th colspan="4" class="subtableheader border-middle-fix">COL TITLE #1</th>
<th colspan="2" class="subtableheader border-middle borderLeft">COL TITLE #2</th>
<th colspan="2" class="subtableheader border-middle">COL TITLE #3</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<tr class="filloutHeight">
<td class="fillout border-middle-left filloutHeight"></td>
<td class="fillout border-middle-fix filloutHeight" colspan="4">
</td>
<td class="fillout border-middle filloutHeight" colspan="2"></td>
<td class="fillout border-middle filloutHeight" colspan="2"></td>
</tr>

<tr class="filloutHeight">
<td class="fillout border-middle-left filloutHeight"></td>
<td class="fillout border-middle-fix filloutHeight" colspan="4">
</td>
<td class="fillout border-middle filloutHeight" colspan="2"></td>
<td class="fillout border-middle filloutHeight" colspan="2"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table id="table3">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="header border-middle-left">Customer</td>
<td class="subheader border-middle-fix">Name</td>
<td colspan="3" class="border-middle fillCustomerName filledout">
Atlantis City</td>
<td class="subheader border-middle">Phone</td>
<td colspan="2" class="fillout border-middle">Phone</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="subheader border-middle-left" colspan="2">Authorized
Representative Name</td>
<td class="fillout border-middle" colspan="6">Name</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="subheader border-middle-left">Email</td>
<td class="fillout border-middle" colspan="7">Email</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="subheader border-middle-left">Address</td>
<td class="border-middle filladdress1 filledout" colspan="7">Street Address</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="8" class="addressRow">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="subheader border-middle-left addressCity">City <span
class="fillAddressCity filledout">ATLANTIS</span></td>
<td class="subheader border-middle addressState">State/Province
<span class="fillAddressState filledout">EE</span></td>
<td class="subheader border-middle addressCountry">Country</td>
<td class="subheader border-middle addressZip">Zip/Postal Code
<span class="fillAddressZip filledout">99999</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="4" class="subheader border-middle-left">The above
vehicles will be used for the following vocation / applications
only:</td>
<td class="fillout border-middle" colspan="4">Vocation</td>
</tr>
<tr class="simple">
<td colspan="8" class="border-middle-left">
<p><b>Customer Certification:</b> All information to go here.</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="4" class="subheader bottomrow bottom-left">Customer
Authorized customer representative signature (REQUIRED)</td>
<td colspan="4" class="subheader bottomrow bottom-right">Date</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div class="footerClass">
<div class="floatleft topmargin">
<p class="">PDF (Rev: 4/2/2014)</p>
</div>
<div class="floatright topmargin">
<p class="">Page 2 of 2</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your CSS is causing the trouble. By removing some lines from your CSS ([style12.css](http://itextpdf.org/documents/style12.css)), I was already able to get a better result ([test12.pdf](http://itextpdf.org/documents/test12.pdf)). It's not perfect yet, but now at least you know where to look: your CSS is too complex. Use Occam's razor to simplify it and you'll get a better result.

Comment: thanks for the comment Bruno and looking it up. I too realized CSS needs rework. I read through the docs again and found the style I am using a few of them are not supported in iText

For anyone else going over my problem. Please note while working with pdf generation from HTML with CSS. CSS should contain only iText compatible tags/style