# Create a new Pdf from an existing Pdf and (HTML + CSS)

Tags: java, html, css, pdf, itext

My use case is that I am generating pdf on the fly. Also I have a pdf with single page. I want to concatenate the newly generated PDF after/before the existing pdf page.

I was already able to generate PDF from HTML (this may result in 2-3 pages) [Pdf from HTML with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32790711/pdf-not-getting-generated-when-using-itext-api-with-css)

I tried looking up at the examples one of which is to concatenate existing PDFs pagewise [Working with existing PDFs - Concatenate](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=123)

Comment: Generating a PDF? why not pdfbox  https://pdfbox.apache.org/

Comment: my HTML content has CSS. PDFBox may not be the best solution in that case

Comment: that must be a joke :D. I am generating PDF through iText pdf library which is java API

Comment: *I tried looking up at the examples one of which is ...* - and what was the problem when trying to use that example for your case?

Comment: actually none I should say I became sloppy. I got my solution here on another thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33045246/generate-pdf-from-multiple-html-pages-using-itext. What I was missing was correct I/O handling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering I was using iText API to generate PDF I got the correct response on an another thread by the developer of iText.
His response can be checked here [Generate PDF from multiple HTML pages using iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33045246/generate-pdf-from-multiple-html-pages-using-itext)

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfImportedPage;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class UtilPDF {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        List<InputStream> pdfs = new ArrayList<InputStream>();

        File pdfDir = new File("C:\\PDF");

        boolean pdfDirectoryExists = true;
        if (!pdfDir.exists()) {
            pdfDirectoryExists = pdfDir.mkdir();
        }

        if (pdfDirectoryExists) {
            pdfs.add(new FileInputStream("C:\\PDF\\Document1.pdf"));
            pdfs.add(new FileInputStream("C:\\PDF\\Document2.pdf"));
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Projects\\FinalDocument_1_2.pdf");
            UtilPDF.concatPDFs(pdfs, output, true);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void concatPDFs(List<InputStream> streamOfPDFFiles, OutputStream outputStream, boolean paginate) {
    Document document = new Document();

    try {
        List<InputStream> pdfs = streamOfPDFFiles;
        List<PdfReader> readers = new ArrayList<PdfReader>();
        int totalPages = 0;
        Iterator<InputStream> iteratorPDFs = pdfs.iterator();

        // Create Readers for the pdfs.
        while (iteratorPDFs.hasNext()) {
            InputStream pdf = iteratorPDFs.next();
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdf);
            readers.add(pdfReader);
            totalPages += pdfReader.getNumberOfPages();
        }

        // Create a writer for the outputstream
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);
        document.open();
        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent(); // Holds the PDF

        // data
        PdfImportedPage page;
        int currentPageNumber = 0;
        int pageOfCurrentReaderPDF = 0;
        Iterator<PdfReader> iteratorPDFReader = readers.iterator();

        // Loop through the PDF files and add to the output.
        while (iteratorPDFReader.hasNext()) {
            PdfReader pdfReader = iteratorPDFReader.next();

            // Create a new page in the target for each source page.
            while (pageOfCurrentReaderPDF < pdfReader.getNumberOfPages()) {
                document.newPage();
                pageOfCurrentReaderPDF++;
                currentPageNumber++;
                page = writer.getImportedPage(pdfReader, pageOfCurrentReaderPDF);
                cb.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);

                // Code for pagination.
                if (paginate) {
                    cb.beginText();
                    cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 9);
                    cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, "" + currentPageNumber + " of " + totalPages,
                            520, 5, 0);
                    cb.endText();
                }
            }
            pageOfCurrentReaderPDF = 0;
        }

        outputStream.flush();
        document.close();
        outputStream.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

        if (document.isOpen())
            document.close();

        try {

            if (outputStream != null)
                outputStream.close();

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: interesting and thanks for the response @Franklin Neves .Trying to understand the solution. It maybe you simply had a sample code and you posted. Still I would like to confirm that is BaseFont. which you are adding on the document I suppose it is not a necessity.

Comment: looked at the solution again @Franklin you are simply concatenating already generated PDF pages. Which exist on the file system. PDF I am generating from HTML I do not want to write it to file system, only the concatenated PDF

Answer (score 0):

This page shows exactly what you request with prepend and append static PDF with composed HTML and CSS content.

http://cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.CustomTipsTricks.InjectPDF

Use instructions are here

http://cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.APIDoc.Usage

Comment: thanks for the info Kevin. We are not generating pdf in UI/javascript but in Java.