# Generate PDF from multiple HTML pages using iText

Tags: java, itext

I know how to generate a single HTML page. I want to know how to generate a single pdf page from pdfs that are generated from multiple HTML pages.

For example There is `HTMLX1.html` and there is another file `HTMLX2.html`
I can generate the individual pdf files `PDFX1.pdf` and `PDFX2.pdf` respectively from the html. I can write them to the file system and then concatenate them as in [iTextConcatenate Example](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=123).

I simply want to know if I can combine this action on the fly without writing them to the file system. I have not been able to identify the missing link

Comment: thanks David for updating the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create PDFX1.pdf, use a `PdfWriter` with a `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead of a `FileOutputStream`:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos1);
```

When concatenating the PDF documents, use a `PdfReader` with a `ByteArrayInputStream`:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos1.toByteArray()));
```

Or you can also use the byte array directly:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(baos1.toByteArray());
```

(Do this similarly for PDFX2.pdf.)

Comment: nice. I was thinking myself I will need to use BufferedOutStream. I am hoping this will do the trick will try it. I will accept I have become a bit sloppy in working with File I/O

Comment: @rhens is there any full fledged working example for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StringReader` and `StringWriter` if you want to avoid writing to a file.

**Oracle docs:**

1. [StringReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html)
2. [StringWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html)

It will still be a I/O process but you won't write to or read from an actual file. Instead, you will use String buffers.

Comment: not most useful way. PDF file is not like other text files. They can be Stored in InputStreamReader but not StringReader.